# Trigger Travis run after Heroku Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, travis-ci

I have a bunch of Integrationtests on Travis, that I need to run **after** my Ruby on Rails app has been deployed to Heroku. How can I do that?

I tried to use the HTTP-POST-Method but [Travis required custom headers and JSON body](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/) and [Heroku does not support both](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks#http-post-hook). Is there another way?

Comment: If you're interested for going with approach #1 of Michal's answer, you can do it [viaSOCKET](https://viasocket.com). I am one of its developers. You neither need to create a custom app, nor deploy anything.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of couple of solutions, but none is perfect.

One: You can create simple app that will translate normal Heroku deploy hook into format acceptable by Travis. Of course you need to host it somewhere, but it is a great use case for Amazon Lambda or similar solution. If you ever wanted to try doing serverless I think you have a perfect case. And the cost of hosting will be almost nothing.

Two: You can use release phase on Heroku. Create a script `bin/notify-travis` and this to your Procfile `release: bin/notify-travis`. The problem is how to get all the information about deployed code like commit sha. For that you can enable lab feature called `dyno-metadata`. It will inject additional config variables, one is `HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT` which contains commit sha. If more data are required, then this solution may not work. Make sure that `bin/notify-travis` returns 0. It will run just before deployment. And if fails, your code won't be deployed.

Three: You can find or write custom buildpack that will send webhook to Travis. The problem is that it will run during build phase. In case of errors your code may not be deployed, but you will send a webhook. And also it can be problematic to get all required information about the build as in solution two.

So you have some options. I guess the first one is the best, but it may not fit your other requirements.